# How can I use my Android smart phone as a microphone for my laptop?

Tags: microphone

I have a USB cable that can connect my Android smartphone to my laptop's USB port. 
This scheme is obviously cheaper than buying a separate standalone computer microphone. My computer's microphone is shoddy, and many people can't hear it well.

Does the answer differ if I receive sound thru:

1. my computer speakers or external speakers connected to my computer?
2. vs. my phone?

Comment: Did you find an answer helpful? Please post feedback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an app specifically designed for that.
For instance [WO mic](http://www.wirelessorange.com/womic/) or [EZ mic](https://www.ez-mic.com/) can do it.
It should work straightforwardly.

A few links that may help:

https://www.wikihow.com/Use-Your-Phone-As-a-Mic#Using-Your-Phone-as-a-Computer-Mic_sub

https://www.technologyhint.com/use-android-as-microphone-pc/

https://www.thewindowsclub.com/turn-your-phone-into-a-microphone-for-pc

https://android.gadgethacks.com/how-to/use-your-android-as-microphone-for-your-pc-0166123/